# How to test sending multiple emails?

Tags: c#, email, testing

Well, I want to write an application (C#) to send many emails at one time. 
It could be a situation - that I need to send from one email server many different messages to many different people.

I'm not really sure, how to do that (so the solution will be most effective) - but first I want to ask you, how to test that task. I mean.. I don't want to send spam to 1million unknown addresses.

I want to check - how long it will takes - Sending 1mln email messages from one server. Is that possible to make that test?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not contact some of the commercial email blasting firms? This'll be one of the things where it boils down to "More $$$ = faster sending".

Comment: Yes, but I want to create a tool for everyone. Company will save an email server in configuration.
So, it could be expensive email account, and free email account.

I have to think, that this tool, will be used by company with free, popular email account (on hotmail or gmail).

Comment: What is the non-spam business case for sending millions of emails in a short period of time?

Comment: An information - for example in banks - you have to send a message to all your clients (I don't know what exactly) - I'm a programmer, so I have to assume that the bank will send many emails in a short period of time.

Comment: What I want to know is - How companies like banks, sends many, many messages to their clients?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options:

1. Setup your own mail server with many mailboxes and send the mail locally.
2. Create a few free email accounts with free e-mail providers and spam them. Do know that if you go this route you will most likely trigger spam filters provided by the hosting server.

Comment: 1. Is there a difference in time - between sending 100 emails to one address from sending 100 emails to 100 different addresses?

Comment: 2. I want to write a component that informs company clients about events. I don't want to send spam.Which route should I go?

Comment: 1. Yes, of course there will be a difference. 2. You could try creating a mailing list or a distribution list.

Comment: 1. So, I'm a developer - I need to create tool for sending emails. 
I don't have time to create 100 free emails accounts. How can I check how long it will take to send 100 emails? 
I mean.. There must be some way - you can not just sell something without testing..

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to test this.

a. **Message Generation:** You would need to test how long C# would take to generate those messages. This would depend on how efficiently you write your message generation code - whether you employ threading, caching, etc.

b. **Message Submission:** You would need to test how fast C# can submit those messages to the server. This would depend on the network bandwidth you have to the email server, as well as how powerful the server is and whether it can handle you sending email to it on multiple threads.

c. **Message Delivery:** This would test how long it takes for the message to reach the user.  This would depend on the server, and is probably not something you can do unless you actually do it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, but I want to test sending one message, from one email server (could be free) to a 1000000 different addresses. Is that possible from free servers like gmail or hotmail ?

Comment: Well, you can always try it with a test account, and see when they block you. My guess is that every large email service has denial of service detection which would flag your account and probably shut it down.

Comment: I agree. but.. There is no way to test sending 10000 emails? legal?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to test the sending of email to many different email addresses, Post Hoc will act as an SMTP server and receive all the email.  You do not need to set up any email account ahead of time, in fact there is no limitation at all on the email addresses used.   All of the email is sequestered on your one host so there is chance of annoying a real person nor accidentally tripping any spam limits.  The overhead for processing each message is extremely small, so you should see no performance problem, even when sending 10,000 email messages.

Open source at:  [Post Hoc GitHub Site](https://github.com/agilepro/posthoc)

Also, check the blog post:  [PostHoc: Testing Applications that Send Email](https://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/posthoc-testing-apps-that-send-email/)